# Formatting an ugly String to list/dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

Thanks for having a look at the following.  From "shelve", I have an ugly set of data.

```
import shelve,os,re

os.chdir('''.\wikiUSstates''')

shelfFile = shelve.open('''.\IndiaTEMP''')
k=shelfFile['indiaprovinces']
print(type(k)) #This is type STR
print(k)
```

RETURNS THE BELOW.  This is provinces of India followed by their capital.

> `<class 'str'>`
> ['Andhra Pradesh – Hyderabad (Proposed Capital:
>   Amaravati in Guntur district. See ', 'below.)', 'Arunachal Pradesh –
>   Itanagar', 'Assam – Dispur', 'Bihar – Patna', 'Goa – Panaji', 'Gujarat
>   – Gandhinagar', 'Haryana – Chandigarh', 'Himachal Pradesh – Shimla',
>   'Jammu & Kashmir – Srinagar (Winter : Jammu)', 'Karnataka –
>   Bangalooru', 'Kerala – Thiruvananthapuram', 'Madhya Pradesh – Bhopal',
>   'Maharashtra – Mumbai', 'Manipur – Imphal', 'Meghalaya – Shillong',
>   'Mizoram – Aizawl', 'Nagaland – Kohima', 'Orissa – Bhubaneswar',
>   'Punjab – Chandigarh', 'Rajasthan – Jaipur', 'Sikkim – Gangtok',
>   'Tamil Nadu – Chennai', 'Tripura – Agartala', 'Uttar Pradesh –
>   Lucknow', 'West Bengal – Kolkata', 'Chhattisgarh – Raipur',
>   'Uttarakhand – Dehradun', 'Jharkhand – Ranchi', 'Telangana – Hyderabad
>   (see ', ' below)', 'Delhi (National Capital Territory of Delhi or NCT)
>   – New Delhi *', 'Andaman & Nicobar Islands – Port Blair', 'Chandigarh
>   – Chandigarh', 'Dadra & Nagar Haveli – Silvasa', 'Daman & Diu –
>   Daman', 'Lakshadweep – Kavaratti', 'Puducherry – Puducherry', '\n',
>   '\n', '\n', '\n']

I am trying to make this data workable (either a list on which I could iterate through index numbers List[0] being province, List[1] the capital, or even better, a dictionary (key being "province", value being "capital").

I tried with REGEX to somehow take out the hyphens and replace them with comas, no success. The ugly newlines at the end of the string would also have to be taken care of (k.replace ??).

Cheers, thanks for the hand!

An enthusiastic beginner.

Comment: Please, provide the input file.

Comment: Original is a scrape from wwwDOTimportantindiaDOTcom/12430/list-of-states-and-capitals-of-india/ .   My XPATH filter is as such: ('''//li[contains(@class, "")]/text()''')

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a start, you can modify and make it work like you want.

```
>>> def clean_string(string):
...     bracket = string.find('(')
...     if bracket > 1:
...         string = string[:bracket]
...     return string.strip()
... 
>>> for line in k:
...     print(list(map(clean_string, line.split('–'))))
... 
['Andhra Pradesh', 'Hyderabad']
['below.)']
['Arunachal Pradesh', 'Itanagar']
['Assam', 'Dispur']
['Bihar', 'Patna']
['Goa', 'Panaji']
['Gujarat', 'Gandhinagar']
['Haryana', 'Chandigarh']
['Himachal Pradesh', 'Shimla']
['Jammu & Kashmir', 'Srinagar']
['Karnataka', 'Bangalooru']
['Kerala', 'Thiruvananthapuram']
['Madhya Pradesh', 'Bhopal']
['Maharashtra', 'Mumbai']
['Manipur', 'Imphal']
['Meghalaya', 'Shillong']
['Mizoram', 'Aizawl']
['Nagaland', 'Kohima']
['Orissa', 'Bhubaneswar']
['Punjab', 'Chandigarh']
['Rajasthan', 'Jaipur']
['Sikkim', 'Gangtok']
['Tamil Nadu', 'Chennai']
['Tripura', 'Agartala']
['Uttar Pradesh', 'Lucknow']
['West Bengal', 'Kolkata']
['Chhattisgarh', 'Raipur']
['Uttarakhand', 'Dehradun']
['Jharkhand', 'Ranchi']
['Telangana', 'Hyderabad']
['below)']
['Delhi', 'New Delhi *']
['Andaman & Nicobar Islands', 'Port Blair']
['Chandigarh', 'Chandigarh']
['Dadra & Nagar Haveli', 'Silvasa']
['Daman & Diu', 'Daman']
['Lakshadweep', 'Kavaratti']
['Puducherry', 'Puducherry']
['']
['']
['']
['']
```

Might help to see if `'–'` is present in the string, so that we don't get garbage values like `['below.)']` and `['']`.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt.  I am trying k.replace(',','\\n') since my output is a compact block, without success (I d love to iterate line per line as you did).  I also cannot "split" on the Hyphens the way you did unfortunately.

Comment: What's the reason you can't do these things? Is it because the original data is in a different format?